# Generating Excel file from HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm aware that I can generate an HTML `<table>` and save it as an .xls file to read into Excel, and that works fine and all, but it only gives me one sheet.

Is there a way to generate HTML so that I can have multiple sheets in a single .xls file? I've tried to simply generate more then one `<table>`, but they just end up getting appended to eachother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer:** No.

**Longer Answer**: You cannot cause an HTML generated page to split into multiple worksheets in an Excel file.  Further, the HTML you generate for even a single page could cause Excel to choke on certain machines as it does the conversion when the file is loaded.  We've seen a number of low powered machines take upwards of 5 minutes to show a HTML file in excel (simple table with rows/columns, nothing fancy) depending on size.

**Better Answer:** Use a third party product like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) or [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) to generate a proper xlsx file.

Comment: I've simply gone with generating an XML file with Excel headers. This works great.

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be way though I didn't try it, see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kaushikborah28/79Nick08302007171404PM/79Nick.aspx and check the Worksheets attribute

check the official documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa155477%28office.10%29.aspx

After installing the Help file you can find an example of a file with 3 Worksheets in XML Reference / Excel Workbook...

Answer (score 0):

You can use open source [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/), а wrapper around OpenXML to conveniently generate xlsx files - i.e. Office 2007+ format Excel files.